# Cannot display information using axios and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect

I'm trying to display the information that I retrieved from the weather server. I `console.log(data)` and it works but I'm having trouble displaying it on the interface. Im guessing the problem might relate to the way that I use async and await. Does anyone know what would be the potential issue?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './Page_Styled.css'
import axios from 'axios';

const BASE_URL = "https://www.metaweather.com/api/location";
const CROSS_DOMAIN = "https://the-ultimate-api-challenge.herokuapp.com"
const REQUEST_URL = `${CROSS_DOMAIN}/${BASE_URL}`


function Page() {
    const [data, setData] = useState("");


    useEffect(async () => {
        await axios.get(`${REQUEST_URL}/1103816`)
        .then(res => {
            const weatherData = res.data;
            setData(weatherData);
        })
    }, []) 

    return (
        <div className="mx-auto page--container">
        {!data === "" &&
            <Card>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>This is Weather Card</Card.Title>
                    {/* Location */}
                    <Card.Text>Min degree: {data.consolidated_weather[0].min_temp}</Card.Text> 
                    {/* Maximum degree */}
                    <Card.Text>Max degree: {data.consolidated_weather[0].max_temp}</Card.Text>
                    {/* Minimum degree */}
                    <Card.Text>Location: {data.parent.title}</Card.Text>
                    </Card.Body>
            </Card>
            }
            {data === "" && <p>Program cannot progress</p>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Page
```

Comment: Please include the output of `console.log` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need not use `then` when using `async await`
Please try updating your `useEffect` as

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      let res = await axios.get(`${REQUEST_URL}/1103816`);
      setData(res.data);
    }
    getData()
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${REQUEST_URL}/1103816`);
    if (response.data) {
       setData(weatherData);
    }
  });
});
```